# Is it possible to create TShape controls programmatically?

Tags: delphi, canvas

I wonder if there is some way to create `TShape` controls programmatically during runtime. For example, insteed of putting 100 shapes, hide them and when the program runs, show them, 100 shapes could be created over some time (5 shapes created in 5 seconds, 10 in 10 seconds, 15 in 15 seconds, and so on).

Comment: Something like: procedure TForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
     With Tshape.Create(self) do
      begin
        Parent := self;
        Left := xxx
      end;
end; ??

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: GExperts and CnWizards have button to convert any visual component into code. Perhaps such questions "how make VCL components a code" are all be considered duplicate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **not** draw and animate by using controls. Instead, you should draw manually using plain GDI or some other API. For an example, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224075/282848) or [this example from one of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16134521/282848).

Anyhow, a simple answer to your question: Put a `TTimer` on your form and set its `Interval` to `250`, and write:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FShapes: array of TShape;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(FShapes, Length(FShapes) + 1); // Ugly!
  FShapes[high(FShapes)] := TShape.Create(Self);
  FShapes[high(FShapes)].Parent := Self;
  FShapes[high(FShapes)].Width := Random(100);
  FShapes[high(FShapes)].Height := Random(100);
  FShapes[high(FShapes)].Left := Random(Width - FShapes[high(FShapes)].Width);
  FShapes[high(FShapes)].Top := Random(Height - FShapes[high(FShapes)].Height);
  FShapes[high(FShapes)].Brush.Color := RGB(Random(255), Random(255), Random(255));
  FShapes[high(FShapes)].Shape := TShapeType(random(ord(high(TShapeType))))
end;

end.
```

Comment: @user2296565: It's all there. It's a private field of the form class.